# Как реализовать Factories с несколькими отношениями в Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Есть 4 моделя: Orders, OrderDetails, OrdersMarkets, OrdersInventories

Orders -> OrderDetails HasMany

OrderDetails -> OrdersMarkets, OrdersInventories BelongsToMany

Создаю Factory но выдаёт ошибку при создании пивот записи, order_details_id doesn't have default value

Сам код

```
class OrdersSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $inventory = Inventory::all()->random();
        $details = OrderDetails::factory();
        $markets = OrdersMarkets::factory()->count(2);
        $inventories = OrdersInventories::factory()->count(2);
        $orders = Orders::factory()
            ->has($details->count(2)
                ->hasAttached(
                    $inventories, ['inventory_id' => $inventory->id], 'inventories'
                )
                ->hasAttached(
                    $markets, ['market_id' => $inventory->market_id], 'markets'
                ), 'order_details'
            )
            ->count(10000)
            ->create();
    }
}
```

Вроде все делаю по документации, но...

Comment: Так а где вы в таблицу заполняете `order_details_id`? При создании, на это поле и ругается, что оно не заполняется.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar при заполнении OrdersInventories, точнее говоря в пивот таблице orders_inventories